# Restarted PC and my network controller can no longer be found

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

Pretty much what the subject says; I did a restart of my computer and now my network controller (it's integrated in my Asus motherboard: ASUS M5A97 R2.0) doesn't appear anymore as detected hardware; the cable is plugged in but there's no light indicating it's working (said cable was working fine around 20 minutes ago before I did the initial restart).  If I go to Device Manager, there isn't even an option for Network adapters unless I go to View > Show Hidden Devices and the Windows network wizard thing tells me it can't find any network hardware.  Running the troubelshooter tells me that the driver isn't installed properly, so I loaded up the CD that came with my motherboard and browsed to the driver install, but when I run it I get an error that says "The Realtek Network Controller was not found.  If Deep Sleep Mode is enabled Please Plug the Cable" (exactly like that, bad English and all).  As I said before under Device Manager it doesn't even show there being a network adapter at all.  In the BIOS however it says "Realtek LAN Controller" is set to Enabled.

What else can I do to get my network adapter back?  I'm stuck without internet on my main computer now because nothing is being detected.  I tried to run a System Restore back to a couple of days ago, but it didn't fix the issue.

Just to confirm it's not the ethernet cable, I tried it on a different computer and it works fine.  So it's a matter of the network controller not being detected.

Comment: Remove the any recent updates that were installed.

Comment: There were no updates.  I uninstalled a piece of software (Razer Synapse 2.0) and that was it.  After I restarted the network adapter was lost.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall that software?  Have you verified a Ubuntu live installation can detect the device?  If it can't detect it then the device isn't working i.e. defective.

Comment: Haven't been able to get to Windows; after trying a System Restore I'm stuck in a Bluescreen/Repair loop that I'm trying to troubleshoot now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings to make sure that the embedded device is enabled.
If so, verify that it is a hardware issue by booting into a live Linux environment (system rescue cd is good for this). If Linux doesn't find it either then it's probably a hardware issue.
You can then try upgrading your BIOS to the latest version (generally good to set the defaults after doing this, rebooting and then setting any changes you prefer) - kind of a last resort.
If that doesn't fix it then most likely the on-board nic is toast. Get the mobo replaced or use an add-in card.

Comment: I'll try that but I really hope it's not a hardware issue... I literally just bought the mobo around a month ago!

Comment: If it's any consolation at least it will be under warranty.

Comment: Even so it seems kind of ridiculous that a brand new piece of HW can die that fast.  I already had the same thing happen with a brand new $200 gfx card (defective out of the box).

Comment: Happens. Had a fairly new GTX 660 Ti go tits up on me, took Asus over 6 weeks to replace it (ouch). Was stuck with embedded graphics for way too long. I think Asus has a cross ship program for mobos, maybe your manufacturer does as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late here, but I had experienced the same issue on my Asus laptop recently: my network adapter gone missing abruptly. (It's Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless and laptop is ASUS N550JK.)

Tried various things like rebooting, reinstalling drivers, applying all Windows updates, upgrading to Windows 10 - nothing helped.

And then I tried to check whether there are any updates to the BIOS. There were several of them actually.

So, I installed WinFlash, downloaded BIOS updates from ASUS site for my particular laptop model and updated my BIOS step by step (update by update) to the latest version => WiFi is back!